# Diacritics in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, utf-8

I having some issues displaying diacritics in ggplot2 plots.

The MWE:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(
  n = c(1, 1),
  ph = c("a", "b")
)

tbl %>%
  ggplot(aes(ph, n)) +
  # can change typeface to anything that supports diacritics
  theme(text = element_text(family = "DejaVu Sans", size = 20)) +
  labs(title = "t\u0325ʃ\u0325q\u0325j\u033b")
```

The output:

[image: ggplot output]

The expected output:

[image: expected output]

I tried saving the plot with `ggsave()` using `device = cairo_pdf` and `device = svg`) but the output is the same (i.e. the diacritics are placed incorrectly). While using `device = svglite` from the svglite package, generates an `.svg` file that renders correctly in browser and in vector graphics app (Sketch).

How can I ensure diacritics are placed as expected?

My session info:

```
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
 os       macOS Big Sur 10.16         
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_GB.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_GB.UTF-8                              
 date     2021-02-21                  

─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package      * version date       lib source        
 assertthat     0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 backports      1.2.1   2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 broom          0.7.5   2021-02-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 cachem         1.0.4   2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 callr          3.5.1   2020-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 cellranger     1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 cli            2.3.0   2021-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 colorspace     2.0-0   2020-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 convertGraph * 0.1     2016-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 crayon         1.4.1   2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 DBI            1.1.1   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 dbplyr         2.1.0   2021-02-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 desc           1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 devtools       2.3.2   2020-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 digest         0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 dplyr        * 1.0.4   2021-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 ellipsis       0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 evaluate       0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.1)
 farver         2.0.3   2020-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 fastmap        1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 forcats      * 0.5.1   2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 fs             1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 generics       0.1.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 ggplot2      * 3.3.3   2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 glue           1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 gtable         0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 haven          2.3.1   2020-06-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 here           1.0.1   2020-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 hms            1.0.0   2021-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 htmltools      0.5.1.1 2021-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 httr           1.4.2   2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 jsonlite       1.7.2   2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 knitr          1.31    2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 labeling       0.4.2   2020-10-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 lifecycle      1.0.0   2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 lubridate      1.7.9.2 2020-11-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 magrittr       2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 memoise        2.0.0   2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 modelr         0.1.8   2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 munsell        0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pillar         1.4.7   2020-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pkgbuild       1.2.0   2020-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pkgconfig      2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pkgload        1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 prettyunits    1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 processx       3.4.5   2020-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 ps             1.5.0   2020-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 purrr        * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 R6             2.5.0   2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 Rcpp           1.0.6   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 readr        * 1.4.0   2020-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 readxl         1.3.1   2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 remotes        2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 reprex         1.0.0   2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rlang          0.4.10  2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rmarkdown      2.7     2021-02-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 rprojroot      2.0.2   2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rsconnect      0.8.16  2019-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rstudioapi     0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rsvg         * 2.1     2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rvest          0.3.6   2020-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 scales         1.1.1   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 sessioninfo    1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 stringi        1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 stringr      * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 svglite      * 2.0.0   2021-02-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 systemfonts    1.0.1   2021-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 testthat       3.0.2   2021-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 tibble       * 3.0.6   2021-01-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 tidyr        * 1.1.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 tidyselect     1.1.0   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 tidyverse    * 1.3.0   2019-11-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 tinytex        0.29    2021-01-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 usethis        2.0.1   2021-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 vctrs          0.3.6   2020-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 withr          2.4.1   2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 xfun           0.21    2021-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 xml2           1.3.2   2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 yaml           2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
```

Comment: Possibly relevant if you might want to use the ragg device: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/modern-text-features/

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Tried different typefaces, but the diacritics are not placed correctly. Also tried to register the typeface and set `mark = 1` in `font_feature()`.

Comment: seems device dependent.  On my Linux system I get expected output